# Method to identify the point where numbers fall off sharply

Tags: python, statistics, controls, trend

I have a series of numbers:

```
numbers = [100, 101, 99, 102, 99, 98, 100,  97.5, 98, 99, 95, 93, 90, 85, 80]
```

[image: plot of numbers]

It's very to see by eye that the numbers start to fall sharply roughly around 10, but is there a simple way to identify that point (or close to it) on the x axis?

This is being done in retrospect, so you can use the entire list of numbers to select the x axis point where the dropoff accelerates.

Python solutions are preferred, but pseudo-code or a general methodology is fine too.

Comment: Perhaps the point where the difference from one number to the next is greater than half of a standard deviation?

Comment: I guess it depends how long the flat period lasts.  If the drop occurs earlier, the standard deviation of the entire series isn't as relevant as the standard deviation leading up to that point.

Comment: Cumulative Z scores would probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this ended up fitting my needs.  I calculate a running mean, std deviation, and cdf from a t distribution to tell me how unlikely each successive value is.

This only works with decreases since I am only checking for cdf < 0.05 but it works very well.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numbers = np.array([100, 101, 99, 102, 99, 98, 100,  97.5, 98, 99, 95, 93, 90, 85, 80])

# Calculate a running mean
cum_mean = numbers.cumsum() / (np.arange(len(numbers)) + 1)

# Calculate a running standard deviation
cum_std = np.array([numbers[:i].std() for i in range(len(numbers))])

# Calculate a z value 
cum_z =  (numbers[1:] - cum_mean[:-1]) / cum_std[:-1]

# Add in NA vals to account for records without sample size
z_vals = np.concatenate((np.zeros(1+2), cum_z[2:]), axis=0)

# Calculate cdf 
cum_t = np.array([stats.t.cdf(z, i) for i, z in enumerate(z_vals)])

# Identify first number to fall below threshold
first_deviation = np.where(cum_t < 0.05)[0].min()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# plot the numbers and the point immediately prior to the decrease
ax.plot(numbers)
ax.axvline(first_deviation-1, color='red')
```

[image: numbers with drop detected]